# Delete rows based on multiple conditions within a column (using Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I wish to remove the rows from if the column contains a certain value(s)

```
  value   pod

  1       hi
  2       ok
  3       no
  4       sure
```

Desired output:

```
  value   pod

  2       ok
  4       sure
```

I wish to remove the row if the pod column contains the word 'hi' or the word 'no'

This is what I am doing

```
df1 = df.drop(df.index[df['pod'] == 'hi', 'no'], inplace = True)
```

I keep getting this error:

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

I am still researching this, any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should use `isin`:

```
df1 = df[~df['pod'].isin(['hi','no']) ]

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   value   pod
1      2    ok
3      4  sure
```

On the other note, look at the following:

```
df.drop(df.index[df['pod'] == 'hi', 'no'], inplace = True)
```

if it were to work, `inplace=True` forces the `drop` command to work **inplace**, and return `None`. So

```
df1 = df.drop(df.index[df['pod'] == 'hi', 'no'], inplace = True)
```

would mean that `df1` is `None`, not a dataframe.

Comment: ok, thank you. I just tried the first suggestion and still have the same number of rows. Let me try the latter- Does it matter that I have multiple columns?

Comment: It wouldn't matter if you have more columns. It does matter, if you have other stuff in the cell. For example `'hi '` cannot be detected with `isin(['hi','no'])`.

Comment: ok @quang, does it matter if my datatype is showing Object and not string?

Comment: I will accept because it works with my sample dataset, but it is not working with my full dataset for some reason. I have only 3 columns in the full dataset. The values I wish to remove resemble this: SJ4, IA9  etc - not sure why it would not work

Comment: column of strings does have `dtype='object'`, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi, @quang Hoang, I used this, and it works:  df2[~df2.pod.str.contains('ID1')]  - not sure why the latter did not work for the full dataset. Thanks

Comment: @Lynnette like I said `'hi '`, with a trailing space, cannot be detected with `isin`, which finds the **exact value**. `str.contains` searches for a substring and would work.